# How can I change a grayscale pixel value by a colored value given the value of the pixel not the coordinate

Tags: python, image, image-processing, grayscale

I want to change a grayscale pixel value by a colored value given the value of the pixel not by the coordinate. 
I know how to do it given the coordinate:

```
I = np.dstack([im, im, im])
x = 5
y = 5
I[x, y, :] = [1, 0, 0]
plt.imshow(I, interpolation='nearest' )
```

But how to do it in values like I[im == 10] = [1, 0 ,0]
doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by `I[im == 5]` ? Do you want to change **all** the pixels like, for instance [1,0,0], into [200,0,0] ?

Comment: I edit the question: i want to change all the pixels that equal 10 to the red value[1,0,0].

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this, although it might be dirty :

```
while [10,10,10] in I:
    I[I.index([10,10,10])] = [1,0,0]
```